# Should I just always Convert.ToInt32 my integers to account for potential nullable integers?

Tags: c#, vb.net

If my [MSSQL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/default.aspx) database contains a data type that is NULL (i.e. null is allowed) then [ORMs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping), such as [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) in my case, create .NET objects that are nullable.

This is great, and the way I use nullables is like this:

**C#**

```
int? someInt = 5;

int newInt = someInt.Value; // woot
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim someInt As Integer?

Dim newInt As Integer = someInt.Value ' hooray
```

However, recently I had to make a change to the database to make an Id field no longer NULL (nullable). This means that `.Value` is now broken. This is a nuisance if the Id property is used a lot.

One solution that I thought of is to just use `Convert.ToInt32` on Id fields so it doesn't matter if an int is nullable or not.

**C#**

```
int newInt = Convert.ToInt32(someInt); // always compiles
```

**VB.NET**

```
Dim newInt As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(someInt) ' always compiles
```

Is this a bad approach and are there any alternatives?

Comment: Why don't you just make the `someInt ` in your class non nullable?

Comment: if your id columns can be null I think you have serious issues with your database design.

Comment: @Ӎσᶎ Specifically the Id columns are for relationships (i.e. foreign keys). In some cases an object may or may not have an associated object (0 or 1) and therefore NULL is a requirement. Unless you have a better solution?

Comment: referring to primary key columns and foreign key columns rather than id columns would make your question clearer. Not to mention that some databases provide IDENTITY as a column type.

Comment: I really don't understand. Are you saying that you have `int? someInt`, where `someInt.Value` doesn't work, but `Convert.ToInt32(someInt)` does? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @svick It doesn't work if your `int?` changes to an `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first off, if a field is nullable, that means it may not have a value.  Ints always have a value.  If you must for some reason fake a value, then use `someNullable.GetValueOrDefault()` (which btw, allows a parameter to define the default value).

Secondly, the right thing to do when something goes from sometimes having a value to always having a value, is to refactor it as necessary to represent this new behavior.

Your fundamental problem is that you are trying to treat two entirely seperate scenarios as being the same - one way or another you are probably failing to properly model what is taking place.

Comment: +1 Ah I see. So acknowledging that they are different and just refactoring the necessary pieces of code is a better way to go about this?

Comment: @RowanFreeman: Think about it this way. Right now you are in a good position: when your database changes, the code that depends on the database being in the previous state no longer compiles. The compiler is a bug finding machine. If you make the change you suggest then you could make a change to the database that makes the code wrong logically but still compiles, and now the compiler is no longer a bug finding machine. The real moral of the story is: don't go changing your database.